# mv command - how it works?

Tags: linux, mv

I was moving big sized directory (upto 10gb) using **`mv`** command and after some minutes I cancelled it (Ctrl+C).

The **`mv`** process was then stopped and some of the files were copied to the destination directory.

My question is that does **`mv`** command deletes file as soon as it copies file to the destination directory or it deletes all the files at once after finishing copying all the files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're working on the same file system, `mv` does not actually copy the file contents somewhere else and deletes the original. It just moves the pointer to the file (simply speaking), or renames it.

The inode number of `mv`ed files will not change.

When working across file systems, `mv` will only copy and then delete the original files, one by one.

Comment: This is not a clear answer. I interpret your answer as: When working across filesystems, mv copies the first file and then deletes that file, then copies the second file and deletes that file, etc... but I do not see this behaviour on my system? Please clarify what you intended to say.

Comment: Please clarify in how far you do not see this behavior on your system – what is "your system", which filesystems are involved, what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: The files which have been "moved so far" remain in place in both the move from and move to locations after `CTRL-C` combination is used to stop the command execution. Now please answer my question.

Comment: Let me research this and I'll update the post.